# MySQL: Modify column adding auto_increment:

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-administration

I want to change a column of a table adding auto_increment:

```
ALTER TABLE t_bed MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT auto_increment;
```

This is the error:

```
Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 't_bed_ibfk_3' of table 't_room',
```

But the table t_room is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `t_room` table is empty, you can try simply removing the foreign key constraint which is causing the problem:

```
ALTER TABLE t_room DROP FOREIGN KEY t_bed_ibfk_3;
```

Then run your alter statement on the `t_bed` table to make `id` an auto increment column:

```
ALTER TABLE t_bed MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT auto_increment;
```

Finally, you may add back the constraint in the `t_room` table if you still need it.